# How to output a list of integers constructed from a single index from a list of lists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of lists that contain some numbers. I wish to construct an output list of the second index element in each of these lists. I am able to achieve this using a normal loop, but was wondering how it would be possible to achieve the same thing using LINQ?

My current example:

```
List<int> output = new List<int>();
foreach (List<int> list in Data)
    output.Add(list[2]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var output = Data.Select(list => list[2]).ToList();`

This is a direct translation. I think it is much preferable to the manually written loop because it is less redundant and composes well.

Comment: Thanks! I love how powerful LINQ seems, but I'm finding it quite hard to learn.

Comment: Check out 101 LINQ Samples. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b LINQ is an essential skill nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Select`. I would also put a check in to ensure the number expected actually exists:

```
var results = Data.Where(d => d.Count > 2).Select(d => d.list[2]);
```

Comment: That check might better be done with an exception so that possible bugs are not silently swallowed. The end goal is correctness, not freedom of exceptions.

Comment: Very true. Depends on requirements I guess

Comment: you have to use `Count` since Data contains `List` items